# Is there a way to extract Tree depths from a Random Forest model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, tree, random-forest

I have created a Random Forest classifier and I'm **trying to produce a histogram of the depths of the trees of my random forest model**. I'm just not being able to extract the depth of every tree in my forest.

My RF model is called 'RF_optimised' and I've tried the code below to iterate over my trees and visualise which has worked. I have gone through the `estimators_` and `export_graphviz` documentation but there doesn't seem to be a way to extract the actual depth of tree.

```
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO

# Create a string buffer to write to (a fake text file)
f = StringIO()

i_tree = 0
for tree_in_forest in RF_optimised.estimators_:

    export_graphviz(tree_in_forest,out_file=f,
    #feature_names=col,
    filled=True,
    rounded=True,
    proportion=True)

    graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(f.getvalue())
    display(Image(graph.create_png()))
```

I need a function that iterates over the trees in my Random Forest and stores the depth of the trees in a list or data-frame, in order to produce a histogram later. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some exploration in the interpreter shows that each `Tree` instance has a `max_depth` parameter which appears to be what I'm looking for -- again, it's undocumented.

```
[estimator.tree_.max_depth for estimator in RF_optimised.estimators_]
```

did the trick for me :)

Comment: `max_depth` should also be present in estimator as `estimator.max_depth` which is documented in `DecisionTreeClassifier`